# Rails Mongoid timestamps seems not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, timestamp, mongoid

Here is my model **message.rb**:

```
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  embedded_in :room

  field :content
  field :user_id # That's the guest_id; room_id if it's a room's owner message.

end
```

The timestamp *created_at* supposed to be automatically created by the Mongoid, but there is no such attribute Message.created_at in the database. I can't understand why.

The embeds_many model:

```
class Room
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  embeds_one :guest
  embeds_many :messages

  has_secure_password
  field :password_digest
  field :owner_name
  field :url

end
```

This is how I create the Room:

```
  def create

    @room = Room.new(room_params)
    @room.password_confirmation = @room.password # Easy way to bypass the has_secure_password confirmation.
    @room.url = generate_url
    respond_to do |format|
      if @room.save
        session[@room.id.to_s.to_sym] = true
        format.html { redirect_to "/chat/" + @room.url, notice: 'Room was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @room }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @room.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is how I create the Messages:

```
  def write_message
    @room = Room.find(params[:id])
    @room.messages.build(content: params[:message], user_id: params[:user_id])
    if @room.save
      render json: true
    else
      render json: @room.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

  end
```

I'm using Rails 4.0.0, and Mongoid 4.0.0.beta1.

Comment: @muistooshort I have edited with it.

Comment: how do you create the objects ?

Comment: @artmees Edited with the objects creation methods.

Comment: every thing look ok in the creation... where do you find the `@room.created_at` printing `nil` or undefined error ?

Comment: @artmees I am using an app called Robomongo, so I can look inside the collections, there's no field of timestamps. Also when I print message.created_at I get nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try modifying the Room class to be

```
class Room
  ...
  embeds_many :messages, cascade_callbacks: true
  ...
end
```